# ShellExecute hold screen after execution and wait for character

Tags: winapi, shellexecute, mql5

```
#import "shell32.dll" 

int ShellExecuteW(int hwnd,string operation,string file,string parameters,string directory,int showCmd); 

#import
string strParameters = "/c terms.exe";

    int result = ShellExecuteW(0, "open", "cmd.exe", strParameters , NULL, 1);

    if (result <= 32) Print("Shell Execute Failed: ", result);
```

The above is my code to execute external executable in MQL using the windows 10 ShellExecute command. But there is a problem in the program and that I see on the terminal but as the terminal is getting away without letting me read the error I cannot debug the issue. Kindly, let me know how I can hold the screen on till I press key. So that I could be able to read the message.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Don't use `ShellExecute`. It can't report errors properly. It has been replaced by `ShellExecuteEx`. But in this case this is the wrong way to create a new process. Use `CreateProcess` to create a new process. `ShellExecuteEx` is used to execute shell verbs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the "cmd.exe" parameters:

```
string strParameters = "/k terms.exe";
```

This keeps the console window open, after the command has been executed.

Comment: Ok I will try it out.